# Given two arrays A and Q, foreach element of of Q, find the element in A with smallest difference

Tags: arrays, algorithm

Given 2 unsorted array A and Q of differing length. For each element in Q, find a element in A that has the smallest differences.

```
int[] findSmallestDifference(int A[], int Q[]){
   int []result = new int[Q.length];
   // insert code to find difference for each Q
   return result;
}
```

I encountered this problem during a interview, which I provided a couple of solution, but it was mentioned that it wasn't optimal yet.

Solutions I provided:

1. Brute force: foreach A, foreach Q compute difference, O(A*Q)
2. Sort Array A, foreach element of Q, perform binary search to find smallest 
   difference, O(AlogA + QlogA)
3. Sort both A and Q, then we have two pointer on each array to find difference, O(AlogA + QlogQ)

What is the optimal solution that I haven't thought of?

Comment: For your third approach, the time complexity is O( max( A log A, Q log Q))

Comment: There is no solution more optimal than your approach 2 and 3 in terms of time complexity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The catch on the interview might be in details. A and Q have **different length**.

So your solution 2 might be non-optimal if A will have say 16 elements and Q have 1 element.

The optimal solution would be to sort the **smaller** array with good sorting algorithm, for example merge sort, that has worst-case scenario complexity of `O(NlogN)` and then scan **bigger** array and find closest element in **smaller** array via binary sort.

Your solution 2 looks optimal, but it should be rephrased.

- Set S = smaller array, B = bigger array. Sort Array S, foreach element of B, perform binary search to find smallest difference, O(SlogS + BlogS)

Comment: you are right, this was also the solution that I think I was missing.

Answer (score 0):

The following method can be faster it depends on the data in the arrays.
But lets say you have the following two arrays.

`A = {1,2,5,11,13} and Q = {3,5,12}`

Create two new arrays and fill the array so that the value in old array is the index is in the new array. So the size of the new array is largest number in the old array, repeating values are ignored. For example:

an example how it should work (pseudo code):

```
A'=null
Q'=null

A' and Q' have the size of the largest number in A or Q
for i < length(A) i++ {
   A'[A[i]]=A[i]
   B'[B[i]]=B[i]
} 

A'= {1,2,null,null,5,null,....,null,11,null,13}
Q'= {null,null,3,null,5,null,....,12,null}

for i < length(A') i++ {
    if(A[i] == Q[i]){ 
       print(A[i])
    } else if (A[i] == null) {
       for(j=1 j < length(A') j++) {
          if(Q[i+j] != null || Q[i-j] != null){ //here you have to be carfull nto go to -negative indices
              print[Q[i-j],Q[i+j],A[i]]
              Break;
          }
       }
    }

}
```

And then compare the two array's to see if the index of the values are filled.If there not filled find the next index which is filled.

This method speed depends on how sparse the numbers of two array's are distributed. If you have very huge numbers (and far apart) this is probably very sub optimal.

The best case scenario of this algorithm is O(A+Q), the worst case scenario is O(infinite).

Comment: I suppose you need to sort the arrays, which means it won't be better than O(AlogA+QlogQ)?

Comment: why would you need to sort them?

Comment: sorry, I do not get your solution. its seems like you need to check whether an element exist in another array, I don't think you can do it efficiently

Comment: what if the array **A** = `1, 100000005` and **B**  = `3, 600000`. Your approach will take minutes to index **A**, even if it has two elements only.

Comment: Then it's a inefficient methods, like I said in the last sentence of the answer.

Comment: The indexing wont take long, finding the nearest element will take long.

Comment: @GijsDenHollander You can't initialise that long array in some programming languages!!!

Comment: This is hypothetical question so the answer is hypothetical.... The implementation is not in the scope of the question. This method could be faster then O(AlogA + QlogQ). thats all it's asked

Answer (score 0):

I have sketch for an idea for the case where |Q| < |A| based on [Quickselect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quickselect). The idea would be to partially sort A while successively processing the elements in Q by searching for the element with the smallest difference in A.

So for the first element in Q you perform a quickselect like search in order to find the element with the smallest difference. This search will cost O(A) but partially sort the elements in Q. The second element in Q will already profit from the first search and further sort A.

I am currently not sure how to calculate the runtime complexity but it could be better than O(A log A) since A will not necessarily be sorted completely after processing all elements in Q. In the **best case it could be O(Q log A)**.

Not sure if it helps, but maybe someone can figure out the missing parts.

Comment: For later elements, it would still take logA to search. It is similar to AlogA actually, unless |Q|<<|A|, in which case it doesn't really matter anyway.

Comment: @vish4071 I don't see how you come to this conclusion. Yes for later elements it will take O(log A) but you are only looking for Q elements so it could go down to O(Q log A) (best case). As I said I don't know about the average case though.

Comment: thats what!! If |Q|~|A|, this is same as AlogA. And if |Q|<<|A|, it doesn't matter bcoz initially, for certain no. of elements, we will be taking O(A).

Comment: @vish4071 I see, so you are saying if Q < log(A) then you can have O(Q * A) instead of O(A log A). I agree. However, imho there are lots of sizes of Q (between log(A) and A) where the above idea could improve the runtime.